# Stanford NLP: "No annotator named sentiment" error

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to apply Sentiment Analysis for a dataset containing tweets that I already collected, for some experiments I run for my thesis. I have followed various tutorials on the Internet and my code is the following so far:

```
public class SentimentAnalyzer {
    public static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public SentimentAnalyzer() {
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment");
         pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    }

    public static int getSentiment(String tweet) {
         int mainSentiment = 0;
         if (tweet != null && tweet.length() > 0) {
             int longest = 0;
             Annotation annotation = pipeline.process(tweet);
             for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
                 Tree tree = sentence.get(SentimentCoreAnnotations.AnnotatedTree.class);
                 int sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree);
                 String partText = sentence.toString();
                 if (partText.length() > longest) {
                     mainSentiment = sentiment;
                     longest = partText.length();
                 }

             }
        }
        return mainSentiment;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run this piece of code, Java returns an Illegal Argument Exception:

```
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator parse
Loading parser from serialized file 
edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ... done [1,4 sec].
Adding annotator sentiment
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No annotator named sentiment
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:78)
    at edu.stanfoJava Result: 1
```

but every single tutorial lists "sentiment" as a valid annotator! The program specifically hangs when calling the StanfordCoreNLP constructor (inside the SentimentAnalyzer constructor) and though I have tried every configuration that I can think of (making the pipeline not-static, creating the pipeline eveytime in getSentiment() method, using a .properties file instead), the problem stays.
I'm using StanfordCoreNLP 3.3.1, along with the models .jar (it's the 3.5.2 version, though) and ejml 0.23 -I have used 3.5.2 version, but with no success.

EDIT:
I replaced 3.3.2 with 3.5.2 and now the error changed:

```
Loading parser from text file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz: expecting BEGIN block; got ��
```

The rest is unreadable and cannot copy that either. It seems that it's a problem with the models library, at least the directory that the error points, belongs to models. I also updated with the latest library from their GitHub repository, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that StanfordCoreNLP v. 1.3.4 was left out from a previous implementation since August. When I removed it, the code started working fine.